# dynamic metatags in view source page angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hi in my requirement i want to update metatags content through dynamically. content was updated successfuly in **INSPECT ELEMENT** but i didn't see updated content in view source page. i want to update metatags in view source page also through dynammic. please help me to solve this requirement. please see my code. i find this code in google. i need to update metatags in view source page must.how? please

```
 <html ng-app="app">
<title ng-bind="metaservice.metaTitle()">Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ metaservice.metaDescription() }}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ metaservice.metaKeywords() }}" /><script>var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.service('MetaService', function() {
   var title = 'Web App';
   var metaDescription = '';
   var metaKeywords = '';
   return {
      set: function(newTitle, newMetaDescription, newKeywords) {
          metaKeywords = newKeywords;
          metaDescription = newMetaDescription;
          title = newTitle; 
      },
      metaTitle: function(){ return title; },
      metaDescription: function() { return metaDescription; },
      metaKeywords: function() { return metaKeywords; }
   }
});app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,MetaService){
  $rootScope.metaservice = MetaService;
  $rootScope.metaservice.set("Web App","desc","blah blah");});</script><body ng-controller="myCtrl"></body></html>
```

Comment: Hi, Did u get the solution for this, If u get just guide me please, am facing this issue now.

Comment: No Solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The view page source is the source downloaded from the server to the browser. What happens in memory doesn't get updated in the source.**

It is the source which was created by server and hence your update on local `DOM` elements does not reflect on the **page source**. It will be show how it was been fetched from server.

Comment: Sorry, but that falls into a different question now and its totally out of topic.. :) Why you want to update meta tags? Also could you please explain _if view source page was not updated how google take my websites metatags content for search purpose_?

Comment: If this has helped you, then you can **upvote** and **accept the answer**.. Happy coding..